# Sonar analysis of C# Website Project with MSBuild.Sonar.Runner

Tags: c#, sonarqube

My solution contains Web Application projects and a couple of Web Site projects. SonarQube analysis works great for Web Application modules, but completely ignores code in Web Site projects. I know that the analysis is also possible using generic sonar runner, but the point is, how to do it using MSBuild.Sonar.Runner ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I'm sorry for such delay, but I've been on vacation. Anyway, I cannot post my production code for obvious reasons, but I've created sample project which is equivalent in the principle: [Sample Project at Goggle Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1HUlU3zCRPVVk5ZTElOai1xWmc/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild) :

> Known Limitations
>
> - Analysis of Web Site Solutions is not supported, however analysis of Web Application Solutions is supported.